# Put os.walk into a list and print in python

Tags: python

I want to get a list of files from a directory and its subdirectories. From the list generated. I want to run a Java program for each file using `subprocess` and write stdout to a single file.  How do I do this?

```
import os
myListOfFiles=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/documents/", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        #print(os.path.join(root, name))
        myListOfFiles.append(os.path.join(root, name))
print myListOfFiles

p = subprocess.Popen('Java -jar avro-tool-1.8.1.jar, '- o report $filename', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: can you post an example of the command line you want to achieve (in command, not with subprocess). PS: your subprocess call is wrong. But I need the working command to help you fix it.

Comment: Sure thing, one sec let me get it for you.

Comment: java -jar avrò-tools-1.8.1.jar repair -o report test.avro

Comment: so `test.avro` is one of the files of the list? or this is `repair` ?

Comment: test.avrò is a file in the list.

Comment: In answer to the post title rather than the body... `print [file for sublist in [files for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/documents/", topdown=False)] for file in sublist]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I won't answer to the first part (directory scan) because your approach works (even if some comments suggest more elegant list-comprehension solutions)

For the `subprocess` part, you're not there yet, so let me answer on that.

You have to pass your command in one single string, not two, or even better in a list, so if, say, the filename has spaces/strange chars in it, `subprocess` will protect the command with quotes.

Then, open a logfile for writing, and run your `Popen` commands in a loop, writing `p.stdout` to the open file:

```
with open("the_log","w") as logfile:
   for inputFile in myListOfFiles:
       p = subprocess.Popen(["java","-jar","avro-tool-1.8.1.jar","repair","-o","report",inputFile],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       logfile.write(p.stdout.read())
       p.wait()
```

Note that standard error will not be written to the output file, unless you pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` as extra argument.

Of course, you could avoid to first scan all files and put them in a list, then perform a second loop as above. You could merge the `subprocess.Popen` call in your `os.walk` loop like this:

```
import os,subprocess

with open("the_log","w") as logfile:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/documents/", topdown=False):
        for name in files:
           inputFile = os.path.join(root, name)
           p = subprocess.Popen(["java","-jar","avro-tool-1.8.1.jar","repair","-o","report",inputFile],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
           logfile.write(p.stdout.read())
           p.wait()
```

Comment: this has helped me out a lot mate, thank you so much.